# how to add custom container bar on top of react native top navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

i Want to create a custom searchbar and a notification icon including header contaner for certain page on top of the top bar navigation ,
the screen should be similar to google playstore , i have been trying this code `const

```
findScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    
    return (
        <View>
            <View style={{flexDirection:"row",justifyContent:'space- 
                 between',padding:10}}>
                  <Searchbar
                     placeholder="Search "
                      inputStyle={{fontSize:15}}
                      style={{
                     borderRadius:20,width:'85%'}}
                    />
                    <TouchableOpacity
                    style={{
                        padding:5,
                    }}> 
                    
                        <FontAwesome5
                                    name={'bell'}
                                    size={30}
                                    color={'#000'}
                               
                                />

                     </TouchableOpacity>
                                
        </View>
<View>
     <App/>
</View>
   

        </View>
    )
}
```

With the below mentioned `code  for the navigation

```
const MyTabs = () => {
  return (

    <Tab.Navigator 
    sceneContainerStyle={props => <MyTabBar {...props} />}

    tabBarOptions= {{
      activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 12,
      },
      scrollEnabled:true,
      
    }}
    >
    <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={AppHomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Clothing" component={AppCategoryScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Learning" component={AppCategoryScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Daily Life" component={AppCategoryScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Category" component={AppCategoryScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Service" component={AppCategoryScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>

  );
}

export default MyTabs;
```

i havent got the desired output.
[image: Google playstore replication screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did add a view with flex=1 and integrate both navigation and search bar under it that was all it took

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a stack navigator inside of your tab nav, you can set the header bar on your screens like so:

```html
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
header: ({route}) => <YourCustomHeaderBar />
}}>
  <Stack.Screen name={MyScreen} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```